# Printing input from user

Tags: python, list

It doesn't want to print out the list entered by the user. I think the problem is in list= []

```
from HeapClass import Heap

def minHeap(list):
        heap = Heap() #

        lst = eval(input("Enter list of numbers: "))

        for v in lst:
                heap.add(v)

        for i in range(len(list)):
                list[len(list) - 1 - i] = heap.remove()

def main():
        list = [] This think the problem is here because it doesn't return a list but when I write list = lst... It does not work either 
        minHeap(list)
        for v in list:
                print(str(v)+  " ", end = " ")

main()
```

Comment: You're not returning anything, and you often forget to save things.

Comment: try converting your `input` to a list, because `input` always takes it in the form of a `string`.
So try `list(lst)`. and you are not returning anything including the input, so do that as well.

Comment: You should rename the variable `list` to something else since it's a datatype/reserved keyword in python. For instance, if you use it as a variable name, you won'tt be able to write things like `list((1,2,3))` to turn a tuple into a list. It can cause some weird errors.

Comment: @ImtiazRaqib Perfect example: *"So try `list(lst)`"* won't work if `list` has been used as a variable name in the same scope/function.

Comment: Oh right, his `main()` has in instance of the `class: List` @jDo

Comment: Try typing `list((1,2,3))` in your interpreter. It should transform the tuple `(1,2,3)` to a `list` and return `[1, 2, 3]`. All is well. Now try typing `list = []` and repeat `list((1,2,3))`. You should now get an error saying `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable` and you won't be able to cast anything to `list` again; it effectively overrides the datatype so what used to be `<type 'type'>` is now a single list of `<type 'list'>`. Overriding built-in stuff gets weird; best to avoid it unless you're intentionally doing meta-programming.

Comment: It still doesn't work. It is supposed to return a min heap. And where should I return the results then?  with 'def main()'? This is due at in an hour and it's driving me insane.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `list` as a variable name. Rename it to something else here `def minHeap(list):`, here `def main(): list = []` and everywhere else. You don't need it.

Also, you don't need the evil `eval()` :)

If you want user input of the format "1,2,3" (comma-separated numbers) to be cast to a list of integers, you could instead do:

`lst = list(input("Enter list of numbers: "))` in python2.7

or

`lst = [int(x) for x in input("Enter list of numbers: ").split(",")]` in python3.

To see why using `list` as a variable name is bad/confusing, try the following:

Type `list((1,2,3))` in your interpreter. It should transform the `tuple` `(1,2,3)` to a `list` and return `[1, 2, 3]`. All is well.

Now try typing `list = []` and repeat `list((1,2,3))`.

You should now get an error saying `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable` and you won't be able to cast anything to `list` again; it effectively overrides the datatype so what used to be `<type 'type'>` is now a single list of `<type 'list'>`. Overriding built-in stuff gets weird; best to avoid it unless you're intentionally doing meta-programming.

Comment: look what i get: builtins.ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 5 6 4 9 45 12'

Comment: @talala *"comma-separated numbers"*. If you want space-separated numbers, `split` on space instead.

Comment: yeah, I realized that. I am just having trouble printing out the result. It print out "[ ]"

Comment: @talala Ok, I don't have your `heapClass` so I can't run your script. It seems weird that it would print out an empty list though. Sure you replaced *all* occurrences of the word `list` with something else? CTRL+H, replace all.

Comment: I did... Thank you for helping!

Comment: @talala You're welcome - I can't do much more though; not without running your script which I can't since I don't have all the code.